# Instantiating tinymce

Tags: tinymce

Ok, I see most examples of tinymce being instantiated like this:

```
tinyMCE.init({.....
```

However, I do it like this:

```
editors[docs_id] = new tinymce.Editor('msgpost'+[docs_id], {        
   .......
});
    editors[docs_id].render();
```

Each editor instance is assigned to the array `editors[docs_id],` and all works very well (I think) this way. Is there any major difference in my way versus the other. Is there any performance issues that I should be concerned with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, i don't think there will be anydifference in performance. You have done it very well.